# Is it possible to find piece of audio inside of mp3 file?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, cut, join

We have a community radio and we are recording all shows 24/7. And we are wondering is there any way to automatically trim those recordings so that all commercials and unwanted parts are cutted off and rest of the show is joined ex. 1hour .mp3 file? So if we add a small 'marker-file' just before and after commercial, is there way that ffmpeg(+filter) can find that 'marker' and do the job?